# A question about connected components of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph. Let $c(G)$ be the number of connected components in a graph G.

I need to prove that for every $e \in E$ : $c(G) \le c(G-e) \le c(G)+1$, where $G-e$ means the graph $G$ without the edge e (you don't remove the vertices).

I tried  to solve that question and while it's pretty intuitive I'm not sure how to write a solution formally. 
My try:

Let $e=${$x,y$} be an edge in $G$ so there is a connected component, let's call it $A$, that $x,y \in A$. So if we remove the edge e: for every other connected component nothing changes. As for $A$, let $a,b \in A$ be vertices in A, so there is a path connecting them. If there is a without the edge $e$ then it means $a,b \in (A-e)$ and we still have $c(G)$ connected terms. Otherwise the path between a and b contains the edge e, so if we remove it there is no path between a and b, hence $A$ is split to two connected terms, which means we now have $c(G)+1$ connected terms.

Is it good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your proof is incomplete. The "state of connectedness" of a graph cannot be demonstrated by a single pair of vertices. Two things are going wrong:

1. If $a$ and $b$ are still connected after you removed $e$, this only means that they are in the same component of $A-e$, but not that $A-e$ is connected.
2. If $a$ and $b$ are no longer connected by a path in $A-e$ this does not *obviously* imply that you created only one new connected component. There might be more.

You can do something like this:

*Proof*.

If $A-e$ is connected, then we have nothing to show. So assume $A-e$ is not connected. Also I am using your notation $e=\{x,y\}$. Define $A_x$ to be the connected component of $A$ containing $x$ and $A_y$ the one containing $y$. Now choose $v\in A$ and its path $P$ (in $A$) to $x$. There are two cases:

- If $e\notin P$ then $P$ is still there in $A-e$. Therefore $v\in A_x$.
- If $e\in P$, then the second last vertex in $P$ must be $y$. The path $P':=vPy$ (the subpath of $P$ from $v$ to $y$) does not contain $e$. Therefore $P'$ exists in $A-e$ and $v\in A_y$.

We showed that any $v\in A$ belongs either to $A_x$ or to $A_y$ and hence there emerged exactly *one* new component. $\square$

Comment: How do you propose to write it then?

Comment: Could you explain why if $e\in P$ then the second last vertex in P must be y?

Comment: @Gabi Think about it. It is $x$ the last vertex in $P$ and hence there can only be one edge in $P$ containing $x$. You got the idea?

Comment: but this edge that contains $x$ doesn't have to be $e$, not sure I'm following

Comment: @Gabi I adapted your notation and you defined $e=\{x,y\}$. Since $e$ is in $P$ an incident to $x$, it must be *the* one edge incident to $x$.

Comment: Okay thank you, now it's clear.